# opencv mat scan random time stealing

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, time, mat

My application is C++ OpenCV based, which needs to detect an object in an image, by threshold filtering. I divided the image into small strips, because of performance reason. I only scan the areas I need to. The image is 2400x1800 pixles. The strips are 1000x50. The Image color space is HSV. As the desired object can be one of few colors (for example 8), I run the filter 8 times per strip. So, in the application, I run the filter a few tens of times.

The application is time critical.

For most of the runs, the strip filter takes <<1 millisecond. 
The problem: Every few filters (can be between 10 to 40, depending on the strip size), the run takes 15 milliseconds (always the same 15 milliseconds)!

The total run which should run in 1-2 milliseconds, runs between 50 to 100 milliseconds, depending on how many times there was a 15 millisecond run.

The heart of the code which accesses the Mat and causes the steal of time looks like this:

```
for i....{  // cols
for j....{    // rows
p1i=img_hsv.at<uchar>(j,i*3+0);  // H 
p2i=img_hsv.at<uchar>(j,i*3+1);  // S
p3i=img_hsv.at<uchar>(j,i*3+2);  // V
}
}
```

Again, the rate of steal increases as the strip size increases. I assume it has something to do with accessing the PC memory resources. I already tries to change the page size, or define the code as critical  section, with no success.
The application is Win32 XP or 7 based.

Appreciate your help.
Many thanks,
HBR.

Comment: Make sure you're using opencv release version since Mat::at() in debug is quite slow...

Answer (score 0):

It is normally not necessary to access pixels individually for filtering operations. You left out the details of your algorithm - maybe you can implement it by using an OpenCV function like [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) and related, which will work on the whole image. These methods are optimized for memory access, so you wouldn't have to spend time to track down timing issues like this.